# Use Linq to shortlist parent records by using Entity Framework relations

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a project with DB-First Entity Framework 5 and .NET framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2013. I have a general requirement that I will explain using one example: in the database there are the following tables:

- company
- user
- company_user << many to many relationship table for
  company and user

After I create the entity model in .NET, my company class contains the following field, among others:

```
public virtual ICollection<company_user> company_user { get; set; }
```

I want to write a linq query that gives me a filtered set of records from the company collection based on the criteria that at least one of the records in its company_user collection has Id == x, where x is some user Id. That means that I want to get the list of all companies that a certain user is related to. Currently I am doing it like this, which is ... not elegant:

```
var cList1 = (from c in db.companies
                            join cu in db.company_user on c.Id equals cu.CompanyId
                        select new
                        {
                            CompanyId = cu.CompanyId,
                            UserId = cu.UserId,
                            CompanyName = c.Name
                        }).ToList().Where(x => x.UserId == u.Id);

        List<company> companies = new List<company>();
        foreach (var cv in cList1)
        {
            company c = new company();
            c.Id = cv.CompanyId;
            c.Name = cv.CompanyName;
            companies.Add(c);
        }

        //companies now has the set of companies that I need
```

Please help me write the most concise query to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance
Zawar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
db.companies.Where(c => c.company_user.Any(cu => cu.UserId == u.Id));
```

Comment: And this is what I love about stackoverflow ;))